# Uniqueness of the function used in the Khinchine criterion for characteristic function

Tags: st.statistics

[Khinchine criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29) for $\varphi$ being a characteristic functions states that it is a ch.f. if and only if $\varphi(0)=1$ and

$\varphi(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t+\theta) \overline{g(\theta)} d\theta$

Is function $g$ uniquely defined for a given $\varphi$?

Comment: No. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener-Khintchine_theorem

Comment: I don't understand the non-uniqueness follows from the material in the Wikipedia article you linked to. Can you explain more, please?

Comment: Many random variables have the same power spectrum.

Comment: So $g$ is the power spectrum?